# Ruby multi-dimensional getter/setter methods (C++-like)

Tags: ruby

is there a way to have 'C'/'C++'-like multi-dimensional variables, that is, define multi-dimensional bracketed getter/setter-methods? (without resorting to Hash)

Can't one define

```
def [][]=(a, b, value)
  ...
end
```

Such that

```
a = Integer.new
a[1][1] = 2
```

?

A Hash should not compensate a proper table. And I think I could remember how once it was shown on stackoverflow how to define multidimensional brackets as method. Yet I can't find the thread, if it existed.

Comment: Ruby does not have a notion of multidimentional array (read: you cannot imply each element of an array to be an array.) You might look at [`Matrix`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html).

Comment: You could have `[]` return an object with a `[]=` method and a reference back to the original object. Or use `def []=(a, b, value)` and say `obj[1,2] = 3` (like `Matrix` from the standard library).

Answer (score 1):

Since C++ and Ruby are so fundamentally different, I'm not sure the question

> is there a way to have 'C'/'C++'-like multi-dimensional variables in Ruby?

does even make sense.

Instead of trying a hard to mimick a C++ feature in Ruby, you should ask yourself what is the real *problem* you want to solve and how can you achieve it using *common* Ruby features.

When you see the `[][]` "operator" in Ruby, it is most of the time actually the `[]` operator returning an Array or a Hash (as pointed out by mu-is-too-short already).

E.g.

```
$ irb
2.6.2 :001 > a = Array.new(3, "0")
 => ["0", "0", "0"] 
2.6.2 :002 > b = Array.new(3, a)
 => [["0", "0", "0"], ["0", "0", "0"], ["0", "0", "0"]] 
2.6.2 :003 > b[1][1]
 => "0"
```